# Added type definitions library doesn't work with jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps, webpack, typescript-definitions

I added `@types/google.maps` type definitions library to the react application and it works fine everywhere except tests: when I run my jest tests I'm getting `"ReferenceError: google is not defined"` everywhere I used `google.maps` types from the library. Has anyone else encountered a similar problem?

Comment: Did you define typedefs location in `typeRoots` of tsconfig.json?

Comment: From documentation: Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder are considered visible. If typeRoots is specified, only packages under typeRoots will be included.

Comment: That is true, but this location is for global typedefs of 3rd party libraries (your dependencies). Your own (your code specific) typedefs placed outside on `node_modules` and thus should be specified in tsconfig for compiler to find.

Comment: @types/google.maps is a third-party library placed in node_modules

Comment: My bad, I was thinking it is your types. Where are you tests seat? I mean how the file of the test different from code files?

Comment: Please share your ts config file.